# Another way to iterate a matrix using a pointer and extract certain values

Tags: c++, matrix

What i was trying to do with this code was to iterate a symmetrical matrix  and count how many negative numbers are above the main diagonal.The output is a random interminable series of numbers. Could anyone please tell me either another way to iterate a matrix using a pointer or where did i do wrong in this one?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void read_array(int *p,int n);

int neg(int *p,int n);
void display(int *p,int n);

void main(){
    int a[20][20],n,*p=&a[0][0];
    cout<<"How many rown and columns would you like to have?"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Insert the numbers in the array"<<endl;
    read_array(p,n);
    display(p,n);
    cout<<"The number of negative numbers above the main diagonal"<<endl;
    neg(p,n);
}


void read_array(int *p,int n){
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            cin>>*(p+i*n+j);
        }
    }
}

int neg(int *p,int n){
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(*(p+i*n+j)<0){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void display(int *p,int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;i<n;j++){
            cout<< *(p+i*n+j)<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **`void main`** is the first wrong thing I noticed. must be `int main` for portable code. that's shorter also.

Comment: also, please fix the **indentation**. right now it's extra work for all readers to decipher the code. instead you should invest some work to tidy it up. note: you can use the free AStyle program to fix the indentation.

Comment: You never print the result of `neg`. Also `conio.h` is non-standard and unused.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: It's not really shorter as you should also add a return statement.

Comment: @user2345215: If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 int neg(int * p, int n) {
     int count = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if(*(p + i * n + j) < 0)
                count++;
     return count;
 }
```

Comment: You should't write comment like that, if somebody helped just vote him up, telling thank is is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
void display(int *p,int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;i<n;j++){
            cout<< *(p+i*n+j)<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

There is a typo, it should be `j<n` in `for(int j=0;i<n;j++){`.

Also your code does not exactly do what you explained in the question. The matrix is not symmetrical and you count through the whole thing not only the upper half.

Your code will behave undefined for inputs `n > 20`. You should use a `std::vector<int>` instead, which you can dynamically adjust for the input. Pointers are not really necessary either. Just pass the `vector` by reference or the array as array and index them in the function like normal arrays.

Comment: I didn't notice that.Thank you!